# What is the output of a function which is not defined for input = 0 (for example because of the division by zero) if we give zero to this function?

Tags: functions

My teacher told me that every function has to be able to assign an output to every input we give to this function. What is than an output for a function which is not defined in zero? Nothing? Or do mathematicians say that it is a convention to say that it returns NOT DEFINED?

Comment: No input, no output. If function $f$ is undefined for input-value $a$, this emans exactly that there is no output-value $f(a)$.

Answer (score 1):

It is not defined since $f(x)$ is defined if and only if $x$ belons to the domain of $f$. When your teacher says “every input”, it is implicit that it is every input *from the domain* of $f$.

Comment: Does it means that I could imagine a function as a machine that assign every input that it can assign to an output? If this function is not "built" for some particular inputs than this "machine" does not accept these inputs because it can't process such inputs. Is this analogy right?

Comment: Yes, that would be a good analogy indeed.